Mechanism to change wheel height when passing a 90 degree threshold

I want to design a board with wheels, that can drive over a 90 degree threshold over a higher ground while staying parallel to the ground. The height of the second level is known and constant.
The movement along the x-axis will be done manually by pulling/pushing the board.
The simplest solution that comes to my mind, would be attach the wheel to the board so that they can move on the y-axis up and down and add ramps before and after the wheel. But the wheel height should lock/latch after the transition, so it can actually bear any load
I think the mechanism I am looking for should contain some bars and linkages before and after the threshold, that drives the seperate mechanism to lower/raise each wheel height before the wheel reaches/passes the threshold and are designed such, that both end positions are locked in y-axis direction, so that the wheel can bear load again
It can be assumed, that the wheel does not have to bear any load during transition, since the board will be longer and have several wheels, that carry the load.
Thank you for your suggestions!

check out the spring systems used on large trucks or consider hydraulics.

Are you hoping to do this passively (or converting some of the forward motive force to move the wheels vertically) or is there a power source available (electric, hydraulic, pneumatic, etc.)? [Edit] the information into your question - not in the comments. Welcome to E.SE.

Please could you modify your diagram to show the complete multiwheeled arrangement rather than just two axles.
